# Calculate $P(2590 \le G_625 \le 2695)$ with the help of the central limit theorem.

Tags: probability-theory

> Assume that you throw a dice with $20$ sides. You gain $10$€ if you throw an even number, but you lose $2$€ if you throw an odd number. For $n \in \Bbb N, n > 0, G_n$ denotes your gain/loss after $n$ throws.
>
> Let $n = 625$. Calculate
>
> $$P(2590 \le G_{625} \le 2695)$$
>
> with the help of the central limit theorem.

I think that I have to define

$$G_n := 10X_n - 2X_n,$$

with $X_n$ being $1$ if the number is even and $0$ otherwise.

The $X_n$ are independent from each other.

Now we receive

$$E(G_n) = E(10X_n - 2X_n) = 10E(X_n) - 2E(X_n) = 4,$$

which seems like a decent result.

For the variance, we receive (due to the independence)

$$Var(G_n) = Var(10X_n - 2X_n) = 10Var(X_n) - 2Var(X_n) = 2.$$

This also means that

$$\sigma = \sqrt 2.$$

First, we want to define the left boundary differently with

$$H_n = {2590 - E(G_n) \ n \over \sigma \sqrt n} = {2590 - 2500 \over \sqrt 2 \ 25} = 2,5456$$

but we weren't given the value for $\phi(2,5456)$ as a hint, hence I believe it's incorrect.

Where did my calculations go wrong?

Comment: You need to be careful with the variance. It is wrong to that $Var(aX) = a Var(x)$. Actually, the correct formulation is
$$ Var(a X) = a^2 Var(X)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start slowly and define $X_i$ as the gain at throw $i$. Clearly $$E[X_i] =4, \ \ \ \ \ \ Var(X_i) = E[X_i^2] - E[X_i]^2 = 10^2/2 + (-2)^2/2 -4^2 = 36$$

Now define $G_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. By basic properties of expectation and variance (assuming $X_i$ iid.) we can conclude that $E[G_n] = 4n, \ Var(G_n)= 36n$, moreover the CLT ensure that for large $n$, $G_n \sim N(4n,36n)$

We now can recenter $G_n$ by defining 
$$H_n := \frac{G_n -4n}{\sqrt{36n}}$$
Which is now $H_n \sim N(0,1)$. This transforms the probability :
$$
P(2590 \leq G_n \leq 2695) = P(\frac{2590- 4n}{6\sqrt{n}} \leq H_n \leq \frac{2695 - 4n}{6\sqrt{n}})
$$
Plugging $n = 625$ :
$$
P(2590 \leq G_{625} \leq 2695) = P(3/5 \leq H_{625} \leq 13/10) = \Phi(13/10) - \Phi(3/5)
$$
Since $H_n$ is reduced-centered, $H_{625} \sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Ah yes, that was a $6,$ not a $5,$ in the hundreds place. Too many digits in this question.

Comment: Thanks! How did you calculate$ E(X_i^2)$ though? Don't we have something like $E(X_i^2) = E((10X_i - 2X_i)^2)$?

Comment: That's a well-known "shortcut" formula for the variance (Wikipedia is your friend): 
$$
Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2
$$
However if you want the standard version, you first compute $E[X] = 4$ then you apply the definition of the variance :
$$
Var(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[(X-4)^2] = (10-4)^2 \cdot \frac12 + (-2-4)^2 \cdot \frac12 = 36
$$
(However if you don't know how to compute the variance of a 2-states discrete random variable, you should maybe revise that first :p )

Comment: Nah, I know that $Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$, but I don't see how you computed specifically $E(X^2)$. :)

Comment: $E[X^2]$ is define to be $\sum_x x^2 \cdot p_X(x)$. Which means that you sum the square of the possible value of the random variable times their probability. In this case $X$ can be either $10$ or $-2$ w.p. $\frac12$ each. Therefore $E[X^2] = 10^2 \cdot \frac12 + (-2)^2 \cdot \frac12$